# Change the return type in Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to write an async task that will return a custom object.

```
@Override

        protected String doInBackground(String... stations) {

            Path pt= doSearch(source.getText().toString(),destination.getText().toString());

            return pt;

        }
        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
```

Is it possible to return an object of the class `Path` from `doInBackground()` function and use that object in `onPostExecute()` method?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the type of `Result` from your `AsyncTask`

**sample:**

```
private class ViewAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Path> 
{

    @Override   
    protected Path  doInBackground(String... stations) {

        Path pt= doSearch(source.getText().toString(),destination.getText().toString());

        return pt;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Path result) {

    }
}
```

As you could see `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Path>` , Path means the `Result` value of the `doInBackground`

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) of it:

```
    1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
    2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
    3. Result, the type of the result of the background computation.
```

Comment: `onPostExecute(String result)` must be `onPostExecute(Path result)`

Comment: and this  `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Path>` must be  `AsyncTask<String, Void, Path> `

Comment: @Raghunandan right2x, I just directly go to the Result.